Laravel Inertia / download file returns a redirection instead
I have the following route:
Route::post('report', Controllers\ReportController::class)->name('report');

And the controller loads a file and returns it
$path = '/some/path/to/report.xls';
return response()->download($path);

In a standard Laravel/Blade project, a <form method="post">@csrf</form> works fine.
In Inertia/vue3 this is my code:
<script setup>
const form = useForm({
  some:   null,
  fields: null,
});
</script>
<form u/submit.prevent="form.post(route('report'))" >
    <input v-model="form.some" />
    <input v-model="form.fields" />
    <button type="submit">download</button>
</form>

Instead of downloading the generated file, the route returns a 302 redirection and the browser refreshes the page. I cannot make a link to the file to be downloaded, as it is generated depending on the data from the form.
What am I doing wrong?

It may not be exact answer to you question, we don't know what code is inside controller but few things worth checking:
Type of response that comes from ReportController and what headers there are. eg, taken from domPDF we are using in our project:
`
public function stream(string $filename = 'document.pdf'): Response
{
    $output = $this->output();

    return new Response($output, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"',
    ]);
}`

Another solution can be response()->download() or response()->streamDownload()
Documented here:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#file-downloads

And if the file comes from the API, you might need this too:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-file-download

Lastly, I'm not sure if it's possible to download file same time using useForm helper(haven't tested it myself), so you might need to fallback for router.post() of axios/fetch requests.
Cheers.
